# Stop Jackson custom Date Serializer writing nulls

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm using Jackson to handle JSON, I have a custom date serializer for formatting dates in the way that I want but it doesn't abide the @JsonSerialize(include = Inclusion.NON_NULL) annotations. The serializer is below.

If the date is null it still gets written. If I don't use the custom serializer all is fine, null values don't get written. My question is, is there something in the JsonSerializer class that needs to be done to stop null values being written?

```
public class DateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date>
{
    @Override
    public final void serialize(Date date, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
    {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(MY_FORMAT);
        jgen.writeString(sdf.format(date));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that it wasn't the serializer at all, but the @JsonSerialize annotation that defaults to include=ALWAYS which overrides the include=NON_NULL on the class. So changing the annotation of the getter works:

changed:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = DateSerializer.class)
public Date getDate()
{
    return date;
}
```

to:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = DateSerializer.class,
        include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
public Date getDate()
{
    return date;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the jacksons's versions? Have the same issue but can't get out of null values after custom serializer result..

Answer (score 0):

Seems that from 2.1.4 to 2.4.2 this behaviour has been fixed and a general

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
```

does the trick now.

Answer (score -1):

You can crete a Serializaer/Deserializer for your Custom Date format.

For the Deserializer:

```
public class JsonDateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Date> {

    private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat;

    static {
        dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'");
        dateFormat.setTimeZone(SimpleTimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    }

    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonParser jsonparser, DeserializationContext deserializationcontext) throws IOException {
        String date = jsonparser.getText();
        if (date != null && !"".equals(date)) {
            try {
                return dateFormat.parse(date);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                throw new JsonParseException(jsonparser, e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

For the Serializer:

```
public class JsonDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date> {

    private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat;

    static {
        dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'");
        dateFormat.setTimeZone(SimpleTimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Date date, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);
        gen.writeString(formattedDate);
    }
}
```

And in your POJO:

```
@Data
public class Person implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8041031461422721556L;

    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @JsonSerialize(using = JsonDateSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = JsonDateDeserializer.class)
    private Date dob;

}
```